# SQL unable to cast object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.iformatprovider' error in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to run this Query in my VB Application but receive an error saying:

```
unable to cast object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.iformatprovider' 

SQL = "insert into billing_pdf_archive (reseller_sequence, invoice_number, pdf, worddoc, csv_cdr_file, csv_services_file, sub_total, vat_amount, grand_total, invoice_type, directdebit) values ('" + reseller.ToString + "','" + invoice_number.ToString + "', '" + Replace(reseller_company_name + "-" + invoice_number + ".pdf", " ", "_") + "', '" + Replace(reseller_company_name + "-" + invoice_number + ".doc", " ", "_") + "', '" + Replace(reseller_company_name + "-" + invoice_number.ToString + "_CDR.xlsx", " ", "_") + "', '" + Replace(reseller_company_name + "-" + invoice_number.ToString + "_Services.xlsx", " ", "_") + "', " + total.ToString("F2") + ", " + vat_amount.ToString("F2") + ", " + grand_total.ToString("F2") + ", 'Month End Reseller', '" + customer_direct_debit + "')"
            conn3.ConnectionString = "server=" + global_variables.web_server_ip + "; user id=" + global_variables.web_server_username + "; password=" + global_variables.web_server_password + "; database=" + global_variables.web_server_database + "; "
            conn3.Open()
            myCommand3.Connection = conn3
            myCommand3.CommandText = SQL
            myCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn3.Close()
```

Comment: That's not a SQL error, that's a .NET error.  The SQL parts are irrelevant.  Now, where in that *enormous single line of code* does the error occur?  (Hint: separate code into multiple discrete steps to more easily identify which step fails.)

Comment: its happening in the SQL="" part

Comment: It's happening on the *enormous single line of code*?  How surprising.  Seriously, you need to be more specific.

Comment: 1) Stop concatenating your SQL. Use parameters, and then you can identify the precise variable that's causing the problem. 2) See #1. 3) If you choose to ignore steps #1 and #2, break that enormous line of noise into separate steps so you can narrow down the part that is the problem, and then break that part down into smaller pieces to figure out exactly where the problem is happening. 4) See #1, and stop concatenating your SQL. Use parameters instead.

Comment: And while you're refactoring the query to use SQL parameters, I suggest you use an [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that you can set the `.DataSource` etc. on separate lines to keep it readable. (Or the appropriate variety lke an [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but I'll post it as an answer so that I can post formatted code.  If you do as suggested in the comments and write clean, readable code then it will become obvious where the issue is and how to fix it.  When you have one line that does lots of different things then working out what on that line is causing an issue is all but impossible.  You should use an XML literal for your SQL code, parameters for your values and a connection string builder, e.g.

```
Dim sql = <sql>
              INSERT INTO MyTable
              (
                  Column1,
                  Column2
              )
              VALUES
              (
                  @Column1,
                  @Column2
              )
          </sql>

command.CommandText = sql.Value
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", value1)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", value2)

Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder

builder.DataSource = server
builder.InitialCatalog = database
connection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
```

Now you'll be able to see exactly what part of your code is causing the issue and, if you still can't solve it yourself, will be able to point out where the issue is to us instead of expecting us to read that dog's breakfast.